# Legend with rainbow colours R

Tags: r

I have been trying to create a legend for an R plot with the rainbow option but I am facing some difficulties.

I plot

```
plot(test$a,test$b, col = rainbow(length(test$s))[rank(test$s)])
```

with the colour assigned according to test$s. The problem is that test$s is equal for many values of the data frame test so if than I write

```
    legend('topright',legend=test.sub$s,col=rainbow(length(test.sub$s))
[rank(test.sub$s)])
```

I get in the legend all duplicates of test$s but the colours are correct. Since I don't want the duplicates I wrote

```
    legend('topright',legend=unique(test.sub$s),col=rainbow(length(test.sub$s))
[rank(test.sub$s])
```

but then all the colours are messed up!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that `unique(test.sub$s)` is not the same length as `rainbow(length(test.sub$s))[rank(test.sub$s]`. My solution would be to do:

```
col=rainbow(length(test.sub$s))[rank(test.sub$s)[!duplicated(test.sub$s)]]
```

Comment: I have put legend('topright',legend=unique(test.sub$s),col=rainbow(length(test.sub$s))[rank(test.s‌​ub$s)][!duplicated(test.sub$s)],pch=1,cex=0.8,ncol=6)
but it give me just 2 colours